# How to remove selected values in Antd select/Multiselect component on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, multi-select, antd

I'm using `antd`select for implementing multi-select components.

Ant select has a property called `mode="multiple"`

I want to clear all selected input on the multi-select component when a clear call button is pressed.

Is there any property for `antd` select to clear all selection done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `allowClear` property of [`Select`](https://ant.design/components/select/), which will add a clear icon on hovering the select box.

[image]

If you need to implement a clearing button, you need to do it by yourself, for [example](https://ikcbo.codesandbox.io/):

```js
const N = 30;
const children = [...Array(N).keys()].map(key => (
  <Select.Option key={key}>{key}</Select.Option>
));

export default function App() {
  const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState([]);
  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <Select
        mode="multiple"
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
        placeholder="Please select"
        allowClear
        value={selectedValues}
        onChange={e => setSelectedValues(e)}
      >
        {children}
      </Select>
      <Button type="danger" onClick={() => setSelectedValues([])}>
        Clear Selected
      </Button>
    </FlexBox>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-57074559-ClearMultiSelect]

Comment: I had to do some refactoring but this works. Thanks. [Y]

Comment: I don't understand; why make another button when multiselect input has this built in?

Comment: Are we talking about the same versions? Maybe now its built it.